# Find the closest datetime to desired datetime and loop through list in reverse

Tags: c#, loops

I have a list of data that I've retrieved and is ordered from previous to more recent datetime. I'm trying to loop backwards  in this list based on a time and date I specify, however the date and time in the list won't necessarily be equal to the datetime I specify so I want it to find the closest datetime in the list then iterate backwards. Here's an example:

I want "3/14/2014 8:35:33 AM"

List:

- 3/14/2014 8:32:01 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:32:02 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:32:03 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:32:03 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:33:03 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:33:03 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:36:03 AM
- 3/14/2014 8:37:03 AM

I tried doing this, but I'm really lost I don't know where to go from here:

```
foreach(var item in providerQuoteInfo)
{
   for(int i = providerQuoteInfo.Count; i >= 0; i--)
   {
   }
}
```

And `providerQuoteInfo` is the list of type `ProviderQuote`.

```
public class ProviderQuote
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

So now I want it to start at "3/14/2014 8:33:03 AM" and iterate up the list. How can I do something like that?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Your list is `List<DateTime>` or `List<string>` ?

Comment: my list is of type "ProviderQuote", which carries 4 fields "Bank Name", "TimeStamp", "Bid" and "Ask". Also see my edit @SonerGönül

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming performance isn't a huge concern, this should do the trick:

```
// quotes is the list of ProviderQuotes
// reference is the DateTime being used for comparison
IEnumerable<ProviderQuote> toUse = quotes.TakeWhile(q => q.TimeStamp <= reference)
                                         .Reverse();
foreach (ProviderQuote item in toUse)
{
    // do something with item
}
```

If performance is important, you could consider doing some sort of binary search to find the index of the nearest item and then iterate backwards from that index, though I don't see that providing that much of a performance improvement.

Comment: I've never seen TakeWhile before. Thanks for posting this. Question: What's the difference between TakeWhile() here and just doing a regular Where(q=>q.TimeStamp <= reference)?

Comment: Ye that takewhile is new to me too thanks for this learnt something new today

Comment: @dferraro `TakeWhile` will produce an `IEnumerable` that goes through the collection and stops as soon as it finds an item that does not meet the given condition (and this is essentially what OP described in their requirement). `Where` would go through the whole collection and produce any and all items that match the condition. Since the list appears to be sorted, the resulting set of items should be the same, but `TakeWhile` can prevent a few unnecessary item checks.

Answer (score 1):

You may just filter the sequence with `Where()` method and loop through like below:

```
DateTime inputDateTime = "YOUR DATETIME VALUE";

var desiredListProviderQuote = 
listProviderQuote
 .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
 .Where(x => x.TimeStamp.CompareTo(inputDateTime) <= 0)
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
 .ToList();

foreach (ProviderQuote providerQuote in desiredListProviderQuote)
{
    // DO WHAT YOU WANT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to find the closest =>
Order the list, find the first value that is smaller or equal, find the first value that is bigger or equal (if equal that's your value) if not from those two values take the difference as a timespan. The value with the smallest difference is the closest.

Pseudo code.

```
    var list = new List<DateTime>();
    list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    var target = new DateTime(2014, 3, 14);
    var smaller = list.First(x => x <= target);
    var bigger = list.First(x => x >= target);
    if (smaller == target) Console.WriteLine("Target found");
    else
    {
        var differenceWithSmaller = target - smaller;
        var differenceWithBigger = bigger - target;
        if(differenceWithSmaller < differenceWithBigger) Console.WriteLine("Smaller is closest to target");
        else Console.WriteLine("Bigger is closest to target");
    }
```